# Why HttpClient.GetAsync() Missing part of the content?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

`Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` and `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` receive different responses.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
    var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
    var taskHttpResponse = client.GetAsync(new Uri(@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=abcdefg"));
    Debug.WriteLine(taskHttpResponse.AsTask().Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().AsTask().Result);
}
```

> ```
> {
>   "error": {
>   "code": "request_token_invalid", 
>   "message": "The access token isn't valid."    } }
> ```

[image: WindowsRT]

```
private static void Main() {
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    var taskHttpResponse = client.GetAsync(new Uri(@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=abcdefg"));
    Console.WriteLine(taskHttpResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

> ```
> }  }  "message": "The access token isn't valid."
> ```

[image: .Net]

Are you kidding me?

Comment: Responses should be identical. Use same output stream writers (Debug.WriteLine/Console.WriteLine) and see if it still behave the same.

Comment: You should make the bracket in the same line, please see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md or the Chinese one https://blog.csdn.net/lindexi_gd/article/details/80332860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` that make may the deadlock in UI see https://walterlv.github.io/post/deadlock-in-task-wait.html

I change your code to `await` that can get the result.

[image]

And I find that your code has not Unauthorized that I use `GetStringAsync` will be an exception 401. I think this api cant use without auth.